# How can I put a new value into PutCommand Item if variable is not "undefined" in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-js

As the title said, I want to put a variable into one of its Item **only if the variable is not undefine**.

I've tried this code.

```js
const createNewAccount = new PutCommand({
    TableName: tableName,
    Item : {
        "PK" : email,
        "SK" : type + "#" + school,
        "GSI1SK" : classroom + "#" + name,
    }
});

if(type == "STD"){
    createNewAccount.Item["number"] = number
}

const createNewAccountResponse = await client.send(createNewAccount);
```

Raise the error **"Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'number')"**
at the line `createNewAccount.Item["number"] = number` Also, my number variable is an integer, and **all variables** will not be undefine in this case.

I'm not sure is there a way to exactly solve this problem. If it has, please let me know.

Thank you!

Comment: It looks like what you're calling is not what you posted here. You are populating `createNewAccout` (note the typo) and then passing `createNewStudent` to `client.send`. We cannot help you debug code if you don't post it.

Comment: Sorry for that, I'm forgot to change the name of the send variable, I changed it now.

Comment: I understand the wish to obfuscate the code when posting it online, but you have to make sure to post the same code which is throwing the error. From your error description, there's 99% chance that you have a typo somewhere in the code you're actually running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const createNewAccount = {
    TableName: tableName,
    Item : {
        "PK" : email,
        "SK" : type + "#" + school,
        "GSI1SK" : classroom + "#" + name,
    }
};

if(type == "STD"){
    createNewAccount.Item["number"] = number
}

const createNewAccountResponse = await client.send(new PutCommand(createNewAccount));
```

Here is a full example which I tested:

```js
const { DynamoDBClient } = require("@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb");
const { DynamoDBDocumentClient, PutCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb");

const client = new DynamoDBClient({ region: "eu-west-1" });
const docClient = DynamoDBDocumentClient.from(client);

const go = async () => {
    let type = 'STD';
    let number = 3
    const createNewAccount = {
        TableName: 'Test',
        Item: {
            "PK": '23',
            "SK": 'type' + "#" + 'school',
            "GSI1SK": 'classroom' + "#" + 'name',

        }
    };

    if (type == "STD") {
        createNewAccount.Item["number"] = number
    }

    const createNewAccountResponse = await docClient.send(new PutCommand(createNewAccount));

    console.log(createNewAccountResponse)
}

go();
```

And the result:

```js
{
  '$metadata': {
    httpStatusCode: 200,
    requestId: 'requestId',
    extendedRequestId: undefined,
    cfId: undefined,
    attempts: 1,
    totalRetryDelay: 0
  },
  Attributes: undefined,
  ConsumedCapacity: undefined,
  ItemCollectionMetrics: undefined
}
```

Comment: It still raises the same error "Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'number')" at line `createNewAccount.Item["number"] = number`. I guess the answer from @Quasssnoi that said PutCommand is immutable means that this process is not possible. anyway, thank for the help!

Comment: Please use the code as I present it, you are not modifying PutCommand, but a simple JavaScript Object, which you late pass to the PutCommand construct.

Comment: Does work now, I just notice that you create the js object, not the putCommand object. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to accept it as an answer, and upvote if you like.

Answer (score -1):

`PutCommand` is a class which [does not expose](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/blob/8a65e9f080d7490aad5b051ee6ff2c81fb80832b/lib/lib-dynamodb/src/commands/PutCommand.ts#L86) the properties of the object you use to construct it. It's supposed to be immutable.

Use this:

```js
const createNewAccount = new PutCommand({
    TableName: tableName,
    Item : {
        "PK" : email,
        "SK" : type + "#" + school,
        "GSI1SK" : classroom + "#" + name,
        ...(type == "STD" ? { number } : undefined)
    }
});

const createNewAccountResponse = await client.send(createNewAccount);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I don't know that PutCommand **can't be edit** after construct, so I might use your answer and change the code a little bit. Thanks!

Comment: This will not work, DynamoDB will not allow you to put a value which is `undefined`

Comment: @LeeroyHannigan: most SDK would just skip undefined values, but good to know, thanks.

Comment: I've tried your new code. This line `...(number: type == "STD" ? { number } : undefined)` raise the error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':". What happen? I haven't used this syntax before.

Comment: @Auresol: try now. This is called [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals)

Comment: Does work now, thanks a lot!